# How to download a PDF file with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to download the PDF from the following website: http://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cjsg/getArquivo.do?conversationId=&cdAcordao=16548741

So, the first thing I do is to create a time.sleep to manually solve the reCAPTCHA (I'm not sure if it's possible to automate this). After that, I expect the download to start. However, nothing happens.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    url = "http://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cjsg/getArquivo.do?conversationId=&cdAcordao=16548741"
    service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
         'download.default_directory': 'C:\\Users\....',
         'download.prompt_for_download': False,
         "download.directory_upgrade": True,
         'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True})
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    try:
 
        driver.get(url)

        print('Acesso')

        time.sleep(180)
        
        print('Sucesso!')
        
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        print('Download concluido...')
        
        driver.quit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ocorreu um erro: {e}")
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is that url specifically for the pdf file?  Or it is just a page, and the actual pdf download is somewhere on the page?

Comment: @JohnGordon This URL is loaded and, after the reCAPTCHA, the PDF is loaded in an embedded manner (within the same link I shared)

Comment: If you access that url in a regular browser session, does the pdf file download automatically, with no further action by you?

Comment: @JohnGordon no, it loads the file preview like this: https://ibb.co/s6NG3bN

Comment: Okay, then I'm confused.  If loading that url does not download the pdf, and the code only loads the url and does nothing else, then how did you expect the code to download the pdf?!

Comment: @JohnGordon when I add the "add_experimental_option", shouldn't it access the page and download the file? I tested it with this link, and it worked: https://www.safetyforward.com/docs/legal.pdf

What do you suggest doing in this case?

Comment: That url links DIRECTLY to a pdf, so that's a whole different case, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question, I don't know how to write code that would automatically download an "embedded" pdf, as seems to be the case in the first url.